# New git repository error on first push

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I did `git init`, then I realized I should include the link that I got when I made the repository in GitHub so I did this:

```
git init https://github.com/genadinik/AndroidMakeMoneyFree.git
```

Then I did:

```
git add -all
git commit -m "Adding repository contents"
```

And that worked fine, but then I tried to push and got this error:

```
git push origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `git init` accepts a URL (although I could be wrong).

To add a remote repository run the following

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/genadinik/AndroidMakeMoneyFree.git
```

and for the first push you should use the following command to ensure all tags and such are pushed up.

```
git push -u origin --all
```

Comment: I got this error on the first command: fatal: remote origin already exists.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you should **not** include the url of the GitHub (or other git server) repository in the `git init`. Git is distributed: you can add several remotes.

You initialize a git repository with:

```
git init
```

(optionally followed by the directory, if omitted, the current directory is used).

Then you can **add a remote** as follows:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/genadinik/AndroidMakeMoneyFree.git
```

(or another url)

Here you add a remote you call `origin`. Mind that you can give it another name. You can also decide to add multiple remotes like GitHub, BitBucket, GitLabs, CodePlex,... and push your local copy to all of those remotes.

and then you can push to the `origin` or other remote.

---

If however GitHub already contains files, you better make a `git clone`, and work with the clone.

Answer (score 1):

you must add origin repo

```
git remote add origin <url to repo>
```

see here https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

Comment: it kind of worked, but got this conflict CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .gitignore
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: git status, resolve conflicts, git add, then git commit -a

Answer (score 0):

Few options

1. You do not have a remote.
   `git init` doesnt set the remote so you have to add it manually.

   ```
     git remote add origin https://github.com/genadinik/AndroidMakeMoneyFree.git
   ```
2. You do not have ssh keys
   Generate ssh keys and change the remote url form HTTPS to ssh/git

You need to ssh keys:

---

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Comment: This has not much to do with the problem I think: git complaints it can't find a remote named `origin`, regardless whether that is GitHub or another one.